ffmpeg overlay rounded corner webcam video on main video
I am trying to overlay a webcam video on top of the main video and have the webcam video rounded corners and place it at the bottom left corner of the main video. I want the webcam video to scale down to 400x225 dimension too. I am new in ffmpeg, can any one help.
INFO
main.mp4:- 1920x1080, 60fps, have audio
webcam.mp4:- 1280x1920, 60fps, have audio
Code I have tried:
ffmpeg -i main_video.mp4 -i webcam_video.mp4 -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=400:225[scaled];[0:v][scaled]overlay=10:845" -c:a copy output_video.mp4

The above code works, however, it only showing the rectangular webcam video, but I want to have a border radius of 20 cornered webcam

geq → [1]scale=400:-2,format=yuva420p,geq=lum='p(X,Y)': a='if(gt(abs(W/2-X),W/2-20)*gt(abs(H/2-Y),H/2-20),if(lte(hypot(20-(W/2-abs(W/2-X)),20-(H/2-abs(H/2-Y))),20),255,0),255)'[rounded]; [0][rounded]overlay=...
